# When codimension $k$ degree $d$ submanifold in $\mathbb P^n$ is a complete intersection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Fix $k>1$ and $d>2$. Is there any known estimate on the minimal number $n=n(k,d)$ such that in $\mathbb CP^n$ any smooth submanifold of codimension $k$ and degree $d$ is a complete intersection? I am curious in particular what is known for small $d$ (i.e. $d=3,4,5...$).

This question is of course related to Hartshorne's conjecture, but I guess it should be much easier.

ADDED. Mahdi's comment settles the co-dimension two case ($k=2$). I wonder for $k>2$ is it known at least that $n(k,d)$ is finite for all $d$?

Comment: Hi I assume you mean the degree is equal to $d$, not $n$?  

Comment: For codimension $2$, if $n\geq2d$ then the subscheme is a complete intersection. (Ref.: P.75 in Lectures on equations defining space curves http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr62.pdf)

Comment: Mahdi, thanks a lot for the statement for $k=2$! Karl, yes, I corrected the question.

Comment: The correct spelling is Hartshorne